Duplicates rows on report extension with tables join Business Central
I'm making a reportextension for Business Central.
I added a relation between "Item Unit Of Measure" and "Sales Line" this way :
DataItemLink = "Item No." = field("No."), "Code" = field("Unit of Measure Code");

But when I generate the data in excel for a preview, instead of having a single row with the data I'm adding, it creates a duplicate with the correct data and set NULL for my new fields in the already existing row duplicated.
Here is an example :
RowID | Existing Values | New Values
A     | existing values | NULL, NULL, NULL (wrong values)
A     | existing values | A, B, C (good values)

Expected result :
RowID | Existing Values | New Values
A     | existing values | A, B, C


Please provide the name of the report you are extending.
